# Bool value '\x06' instead of default value 'YES'

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, boolean

Execute the Sqlite library am caught a BOOL value as  '\x06' instead of 'YES' after 4 or 5 steps BOOl value will be '\0'..what is the problem of this BOOL value?

```
BOOL success;//success value is '\x06'
NSLog(@"success:%c",success);

//If the database is present then quit.
if(success)
{
    [self OpenDB:databasePath];
    return;
}

//the database does not exists, so we will copy it to the users document directory]

//Copy the database file to the users document directory.
success = [FileManager copyItemAtPath:dbPath toPath:databasePath error:&error];//  this place success value is '\0'

//If the above operation is not a success then display a message.
//Error message can be seen in the debugger's console window.
if(success)//
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to copy the database. Error: %@.", [error localizedDescription]);
[self OpenDB:databasePath];

Am checking success only....
```

NSLOG output is success:

Comment: Are you really checking `success`'s value before setting it, or did you make a mistake in copying the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use %d instead of %c or try to set a default value to success,
like `BOOL success = NO;`

```
NSLog(@"success: %d", success);
```